# Get XML Element and it's children, and then the values of those children, by name

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to working with xml, and it's starting to get frustrating how difficult it is to do what I need, and everything I've found on google does not work.

```
<Player>
<Name>PoopNUG</Name>
<PlayerTag>DANKMEMES</PlayerTag>
<StartStats>
  <StartNum>2</StartNum>
  <LastUpdated>2015-07-24T22:21:30.5463885-05:00</LastUpdated>
</StartStats>
<CurrentStats>
  <CurrentNum>3</CurrentNum>
  <LastUpdated>2015-07-24T22:21:30.5463885-05:00</LastUpdated>
</CurrentStats>
```

That's an example of xml I'm working with. There are many players in the file. I need to find a player by name, then access the children of that player, and do so by the elements name to work with.

I can pull the correct element using:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> myPlayers =
            from myP in pElements.Elements("Player")
            where (string)myP.Element("Name") == pNameCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()
            select myP;
```

But after that I'm lost. I've tried probably 20 ways I've found on google and nothing works to get at the data in myPlayers. I can print the whole thing out but cannot access individual elements by name and the values of those elements.

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps searching on google is not the best learning strategy for a new language. Have you thought of buying a book?

Answer (score 0):

I did not run the code but you could try out something like this to search your element based on the element name and the value of the attribute name.Of course you can use LINQ directly as well

```
XElement Root = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load("MyFile.xml");
foreach(XElement ChildOfRoot in Root.Elements())
{
     //loop for eleemnt name player/Player
     if(ChildOfRoot.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == "player")
     {
         //compare the of the player.
         if(ChildOfRoot.Attribute("Name").Value == "MyName")
         {
             //once you found the player, loop thorugh its children
              foreach(XElement ChildOfPlayer in ChildOfRoot.Elements())
              {

                      //read the value of child nodes here
               }
               break;
           }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me

```
XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Noname1.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> myPlayers = from myP in xmlDoc.Elements("Player")
                                          where (string)myP.Element("Name") == "PoopNUG"
                                          select myP;

        foreach (XElement player in myPlayers)
        {
            string name = player.Element("Name").Value;
            string tag = player.Element("PlayerTag").Value;
        }
```

and xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<Player>
<Name>PoopNUG</Name>
<PlayerTag>DANKMEMES</PlayerTag>
<StartStats>
  <StartNum>2</StartNum>
  <LastUpdated>2015-07-24T22:21:30.5463885-05:00</LastUpdated>
</StartStats>
<CurrentStats>
  <CurrentNum>3</CurrentNum>
  <LastUpdated>2015-07-24T22:21:30.5463885-05:00</LastUpdated>
</CurrentStats>
</Player>
<Player>
<Name>PoopNUG</Name>
<PlayerTag>DANKMEMES</PlayerTag>
<StartStats>
  <StartNum>2</StartNum>
  <LastUpdated>2015-07-24T22:21:30.5463885-05:00</LastUpdated>
</StartStats>
<CurrentStats>
  <CurrentNum>3</CurrentNum>
  <LastUpdated>2015-07-24T22:21:30.5463885-05:00</LastUpdated>
</CurrentStats>
</Player>
</root>
```